# User defined expanding window in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

Is there a way to modify the expanding windows in Pandas. For example consider a random DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,60,size=(10,3)),columns=["a","b","c"])
df["d1"]=["Apple","Mango","Apple","Apple","Mango","Mango","Apple","Mango","Apple","Apple"]
df["d2"]=["Orange","lemon","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange","lemon","Orange"]
df["date"] = ["2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-01-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01","2002-02-01"]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df


     a   b  c    d1       d2     date
0   16  25  37  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
1   24  41  32  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
2   41  20  53  Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
3   4   28  47  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
4   7   29  10  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
5   6   54  15  Mango   Orange  2002-01-01
6   26  54  35  Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
7   31  4   12  Mango   Orange  2002-02-01
8   33  36  54  Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
9   50  22  48  Apple   Orange  2002-02-01
```

When I to `df.expanding(1).apply()`, it applies the function to expanding every row, is it possible to pass the `date` column to the `expanding function` so instead of every row as a window, it accumulates groups of rows based on `date`

Existing expanding window:

```
window 1: 0 16  25  37  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01

window 2: 0 16  25  37  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
          1 24  41  32  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01

window 3: 0 16  25  37  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
          1 24  41  32  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
          2 41  20  53  Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
```

Expected expanding window:

window 1 (all rows for date "2002-01-01"):

```
0   16  25  37  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
1   24  41  32  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
2   41  20  53  Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
3   4   28  47  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
4   7   29  10  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
5   6   54  15  Mango   Orange  2002-01-01
6   26  54  35  Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
```

window 2 (all rows for date "2002-01-01" and "2002-02-01" ):

```
0   16  25  37  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
1   24  41  32  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
2   41  20  53  Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
3   4   28  47  Apple   Orange  2002-01-01
4   7   29  10  Mango   lemon   2002-01-01
5   6   54  15  Mango   Orange  2002-01-01
6   26  54  35  Apple   lemon   2002-01-01
7   31  4   12  Mango   Orange  2002-02-01
8   33  36  54  Apple   lemon   2002-02-01
9   50  22  48  Apple   Orange  2002-02-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df.date` is sorted.

I suppose that there is more efficient way to calculate `end`. If you find better solution please let me know.

[Another usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64334891/8664422), [Pandas custom window rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#custom-window-rolling), [Possible problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64967769/window-of-full-weeks-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment114868459_64970604)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer
from typing import Optional, Tuple


class CustomIndexer(BaseIndexer):
    def get_window_bounds(self,
                          num_values: int = 0,
                          min_periods: Optional[int] = None,
                          center: Optional[bool] = None,
                          closed: Optional[str] = None
                          ) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
        
        lst = []
        prev_date = self.custom_name[0]
        for i, date in enumerate(self.custom_name[1:], 1):
            if prev_date != date:
                lst.append(i)
                prev_date = date 
        lst.append(len(df))
        
        end = np.array(lst)
        start = np.zeros_like(end)
        
        return start, end
```

```
indexer = CustomIndexer(custom_name=df.date)
for window in df.rolling(indexer):
    print(window)
```

Outputs:

```
    a   b   c     d1      d2       date
0  17  27  35  Apple  Orange 2002-01-01
1  39  10  57  Mango   lemon 2002-01-01
2   8  31  12  Apple   lemon 2002-01-01
3  20  17  23  Apple  Orange 2002-01-01
4  11  26  41  Mango   lemon 2002-01-01
5  52  57   9  Mango  Orange 2002-01-01
6  40  15  33  Apple   lemon 2002-01-01
    a   b   c     d1      d2       date
0  17  27  35  Apple  Orange 2002-01-01
1  39  10  57  Mango   lemon 2002-01-01
2   8  31  12  Apple   lemon 2002-01-01
3  20  17  23  Apple  Orange 2002-01-01
4  11  26  41  Mango   lemon 2002-01-01
5  52  57   9  Mango  Orange 2002-01-01
6  40  15  33  Apple   lemon 2002-01-01
7  17  17  37  Mango  Orange 2002-02-01
8   5  53   0  Apple   lemon 2002-02-01
9  16  10  24  Apple  Orange 2002-02-01
```