# Window of full weeks in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, windowing

I am looking for a special [window function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/computation.html#window-functions) in pandas: sort of a combination of [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) *and* [expanding](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html). For calculating (for instance) the mean and standard deviating, I want to regard all past data, but ignore the first few records to make sure I have a multiple of 7 (days in my case). That's because I know the data has a strong weekly pattern.

Example:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 1, 3],
              pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-22'))
s.rolling(7, 7).mean()   # Use last 7 days.
s.expanding(7).mean()    # Use all past days.
s.mywindowing(7).mean()  # Use last past multiple of 7 days. How?
```

The effect should be like this:
[image: Manual exercise in Excel]

Of course I can do things manually using `for` loops and such, but I imagine the existing pandas machinery can be used to do this...?

Comment: Can you explain how you created the values for for the your function please?

Comment: @NathanFurnal averaging from start up to the current date: a multiple of 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pandas custom window rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#custom-window-rolling)

another usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64334891/8664422)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer
from typing import Optional, Tuple


class CustomIndexer(BaseIndexer):
    def get_window_bounds(self,
                          num_values: int = 0,
                          min_periods: Optional[int] = None,
                          center: Optional[bool] = None,
                          closed: Optional[str] = None
                          ) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:

        end = np.arange(1, num_values+1, dtype=np.int64)
        start = end % 7
        return start, end
```

```
indexer = CustomIndexer(num_values=len(s))
s.rolling(indexer).mean().round(2)
```

Outputs:

```
2020-01-01     NaN
2020-01-02     NaN
2020-01-03     NaN
2020-01-04     NaN
2020-01-05     NaN
2020-01-06     NaN
2020-01-07    3.00
2020-01-08    3.14
2020-01-09    3.29
2020-01-10    3.43
2020-01-11    3.29
2020-01-12    3.43
2020-01-13    3.57
2020-01-14    3.36
2020-01-15    3.36
2020-01-16    3.36
2020-01-17    3.36
2020-01-18    3.36
2020-01-19    3.36
2020-01-20    3.36
2020-01-21    3.24
2020-01-22    3.33
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I *just* found out about `get_window_bounds`, thanks! Now see why `count()` does not work as expected...

Comment: Why use `self.your_custom_name` instead of just `num_values`?

Comment: Note that `.count()` doesn't work correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64984049/357313